# decode json object sent form android app to php server

Tags: php, android, json

I am sending json object from android as such:

```
//Create JSONObject here
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
                    json.put("key", String.valueOf(args[0]));

                    String postData=json.toString();

                    // Send POST output.
                    printout = new DataOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream ());
                    printout.writeUTF(URLEncoder.encode(postData,"UTF-8"));
                    Log.i("NOTIFICATION", "Data Sent");
                    printout.flush ();
                    printout.close ();
```

When it is sent to the server it looks like the following code snippet. `???%7B%22key%22%3A%22value%22%7D`
I should add the first ??? are in a diamond each. When I decode the whole json object I get null. In the php server I have

```
$somevar=json_decode(json, true);
```

which returns null. Can someone point me on how to retrieve the json value? Thanks so much:)

Comment: `URLEncoder.encode` why would you do that?

Comment: also `DataOutputStream`? That's a Java specific stream that adds metadata to the object you write in the stream.

Comment: @njzk2 I am encoding the json object to send it to the server. What other mechanism can I use?

Comment: @njzk2 you are absolutely me hero dude. You saved my life by giving me the hint. I used outputstreamwriter and I got all my json the way it should be. Again thanks so much.

Comment: no problem. Don't forget to explicitly indicate the charset of your writer, to avoid any potential issue with strange locales in the future.

Comment: Yes I did that. I thought it only works with UTF-8? That's what I am using now.

Comment: utf-8 is the standard for json. The 2 important points when indicating an encoding are a/ that your server uses the same (obviously) and b/ that this encoding covers all the characters you intend to use. UTF-8 covers all characters, being an implementation of Unicode. Others (like Latin-1, which is quite widespread) only cover a small subset. (When in doubt, UTF-8 is a good default choice these days)

Comment: @njzk2 this all worked fine in development. But when I deployed my server to the compute engine instance I am receiving null string. Php is saying it receives string(0). But the JSON is still valid and I tested it from browser and it works. Is there any reported bug with php/JSON/Android OutputStreamWriter that you know of?